# Adding Index for Week Of Date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am creating charts using Highcharts from a MySQL database and one of the charts is the number of new listings in a week. I have the date field called ListDate which has an index on it.

Was wondering if I could (and how to do it if I could) and if I should add an index to the week of the ListDate.

Here's my code if it helps:

```
    $Week = 1;
while($Week <= 53)
    {
    $NumListings = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(MLSNumber)
    FROM IRES WHERE 
    City = \"$City\" AND
    WEEK(ListDate,3) = $Week AND
    YEAR(ListDate) = $ThisYear AND
    Category=1 AND
    TotalUnits < 2");

    if($NumListings != "" AND $NumListings > 0 AND !(date("Y") == $ThisYear AND date("W") == $Week))
        {
        $Content .= "               [".$Week.", ".$NumListings."],\n";
        }

    $Week++;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if MySQL supports functional indexes; if it does you could simply `CREATE INDEX week_of_listing ON ires (WEEK(listdate, 3));` If it doesn't, the worst you'll end up with is an error message. ;)

Comment: Yes, that gives me an error.

Comment: Are you looking for the new listings (Category = 1) for every week of the year for a given city except for the current week?

Comment: I would think of it in reverse. Find the start date for the given week, and then use that as the range variable

Answer (score 1):

It has not been possible to do this on MySQL until very recently, support for virtual columns and indexes on them was added in the recently released MySQL 5.7 series.

Details on usage: http://mysqlserverteam.com/virtual-columns-and-effective-functional-indexes-in-innodb/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing 52 queries, I would just run one query to gather the data.

```
SELECT WEEK(ListDate,3) AS week, COUNT(MLSNumber) as new_listings
FROM   IRES
WHERE  City = \"$City\"
AND    ListDate between
       -- The 1st of the year through the last day of the year.
       str_to_date(concat('01-01-', '$ThisYear'),'%m-%d-%Y') and
       str_to_date(concat('12-31-', '$ThisYear'),'%m-%d-%Y')
       -- If $ThisYear is the current year, limit to the most recent full week.
AND    ListDate <= curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day
AND    Category = 1
AND    TotalUnits < 2
GROUP BY WEEK(ListDate,3);
```

You could try different indexes to see what works best, such as

```
index(City)
index(City,Category)
index(City,ListDate,Category)
index(ListDate)
index(ListDate,Category)
index(ListDate,City,Category)
```